# Matlab function works erratically, and some other times returns error

Tags: matlab

```
function [N] = rand_walk1(n)
j = zeros(1,n); %j will be the output vector
i=2;
for i= 2:n        %This 'for' loop will randomly add or subtract 1 to each entry of the vector j, starting from j(2).
   if rand >= 0.5 %This 'if' statement returns 1 or -1 with equal probability (it uses the uniform distribution with parameters [0,1]).
      v = 1;
   elseif rand <0.5
      v = -1;
   end
   j(i)=j(i-1)+v;
end

N = j;
end
```

This is my function, sometimes it works and some other times it returns the following error:

```
Error in rand_walk1 (line 10)
j(i)=j(i-1)+v;
```

Any ideas of why I'm randomly getting this error, while some other times the function works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I added indentation to your code, it's much more clear this way. I suggest that you start doing the same, it's really helpful to yourself in the long run:) Also: consider not using `i` and `j` as variables, since those also refer to the imaginary unit.

Comment: Uv allocated a 1 by n array but assigning only using one argument.. Don't recall if matlab understands that.

Comment: @wbg it does, it's called linear indexing. It can even automatically expand a vector using this syntax (not a matrix, though).

Answer (score 3):

Occasionally, sometimes, `v` is unassigned. Let's look at your random number generation:

```
if rand >= 0.5 
   v = 1;
elseif rand <0.5
   v = -1;
end
```

The first `if` sets `v = 1` half of the time. The other half of the time, you want to set `v = -1`. But what you're doing is creating a new random number and checking that. If that new random number is *also* less than `0.5`, you get a good result. If it's greater than `0.5`, you'll just fall through and `v` will be unchanged. If this is your first time through the loop, there's nothing to change, so `v` will remain unassigned. That's when you get an error.

Instead, you want to do this:

```
if rand >= 0.5 
   v = 1;
else
   v = -1;
end
```

This way, if your result is `< 0.5`, you set `v = -1` **every time**. It's got to be one or the other. You don't have to check again.

---

I'd like to note that one of the reasons this bug was a bit trickier to find is that you called the function `rand` without any parentheses after it. `rand` could be mistaken for a variable name while `rand()` is obviously a function call with no arguments. Not a big deal, and perfectly legal MATLAB, but every little bit helps when it comes to code clarity.

Comment: Extra kudos for `rand()`, +1 :)